# docker build creates two images instead of one with the two components

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i want to build a easy web server to get in touch with docker compose but there are two images build and the webserver doesnt run.

app.js:

```
'use strict';

const cors = require('cors');
const { request } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const {flaschenpost} = request('flaschenpost');
const http = require('http'); 

const logger = flaschenpost.getLogger(); 

const api = express(); 

api.use(cors());

api.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.json(
        {
            now: Date.now()
        });
});

const server = http.createServer(api);
const port = 3_000;

server.listen(post, ()=> {
    logger.info('Server started.', {port});
});
```

my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY --chown=node:node ./package.json ./package.json
COPY --chown=node:node ./package-lock.json ./package-lock.json

RUN npm install --production

COPY --chown=node:node . .

CMD [ "node", "app.js"]
```

`sudo docker build -t api`

`sudo docker run -d --init -p 3000:3000 --name api api`

The output is after running `docker ps`

|REPO |TAG           |IMAGE_ID    |CREATED      |SIZE |

|api  |latest        |f164f3da6ad2|4 minutes ago|127MB|

|node |16.13.0-alpine|44e24535dfbf|12 months ago|110MB|

`curl http://localhost:3000`

outputs this:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 0 ms: Connection refused`

Comment: Docker inspect image api.

Comment: ... ]
Error: No such object: image

Comment: In `server.listen` in your node app, you use `post`. It should be `port`.

Comment: thank you very much, thats correct so i changed it, but it also doesnt run.

Comment: Is the 3000 port listening in the server? `netstat -tnulp | grep 3000` (Same can be checked inside the docker as well)

Also, try removing `--init` in the docker run command.

Comment: did you remove the underscore from `const port = 3_000;` ?
Does the server work if you try to run it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong.
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Now build it

```
docker build -t api .
```

Inspect image to if you get what you really want

```
docker inspect image api:latest 
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:7bbad5c790f4583e19b1dcf3b3c1aeb0a45fc46ad997d54222a51f1867e8789b",
        "RepoTags": [
            "api:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:e58f7a2e8bb5c548475104eb813a6f12b8f610aa939b69de92d349116c2d9a00",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2022-11-14T09:51:03.762665424Z",
```

Comment: Ok, i tried it but it doesnt work. I got the same error as before.

Comment: Show me tree . output from your current terminal.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean with tree? i am very new in this area.